# snmp_exporter (prometheus) - get error type of metrics

Tags: prometheus, snmp

I want to get the serialNO value, which is of type string, but snmp_exporter gets the gauge type, snmp.yml file as follows:

```
  - name: serialNo
    oid: 1.3.6.1.4.1.258.120.1000.6.2.2.2
    type: DisplayString
    help: ' - 1.3.6.1.4.1.258.120.1000.6.2.2.2'
    indexes:
    - labelname: daNo
      type: gauge
```

When you look at it from webui, it looks like this:

```
# HELP serialNo  - 1.3.6.1.4.1.258.120.1000.6.2.2.2
# TYPE serialNo gauge
serialNo{daNo="0",serialNo="Mcc00586 A"} 1
```

SerialNo metric is clearly displaystring, why is the query result of gauge type? Why is the value of erialNO in "{}"? How can I get the value of serialNo correctly?

Comment: If you want help with a snmp exporter question we need to see both your generator.yml and the MIB in question.

Comment: Sorry! I just uploaded the mib file & generator.yml to the link below, please check it, thank you!  https://github.com/zhuoweichen/dam-tmp

Answer (score 1):

`serialNo` is a `DisplayString`. Prometheus values are floats, not strings, so the way that the snmp exporter exposes strings is to do so as labels. This is a form of info metric, which are gauges and [have a value of 1](https://www.robustperception.io/why-info-style-metrics-have-a-value-of-1).